# Зафиксировать размеры проводника win10

Tags: windows-10, explorer

Есть ли способ зафиксировать размер окна проводника, любой его открытой копии так, чтобы нельзя было его растянуть за края, ни по кнопке maximaze ни другим иным спообом?

Comment: В чем смысл этого, какую проблему вы хотите решить?

Comment: Чтобы случайно не изменить размер или кто-то другой не смог изменить размер. Т.к. нет возможности разграничит доступ на разные учетки.